# How to enable checkboxs in Table of Ant Design by conditional?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to disable not selected row when selected row > 3. I did it but I don't know how to get it back from disabling when selected row < 3. What should I do? I tried renderCell return normal Checkbox for `selected.length < 3` but it doesn't work.

Here is my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/selection-ant-design-demo-forked-4s6uo?file=/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to have an additional state for the row selection. The onChange prop of the rowSelection gives you the selected rows . we just need to map over it to get the row keys .

```
onChange: (selectedRowKeys, selectedRows) => {
              setSelected(selectedRows.map(row => row.key))
            },
```

Once you have the row keys, now all we need to do is to check whether a row key is not part of the selected keys . If the selected rows is greater than 2 and the row's key is not in the selected keys then we are disabling it .

```
getCheckboxProps: (record) => {
              if (selected.length > 2) {
                return {
                  disabled: !selected.includes(record.key) 
                };
              }
            }
```

**Complete Code**

```
const Demo = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

  return (
    <Table
      rowSelection={{
        onChange: (selectedRowKeys, selectedRows) => {
          setSelected(selectedRows.map(row => row.key))
        },
        getCheckboxProps: (record) => {
          if (selected.length > 2) {
            return {
              disabled: !selected.includes(record.key) 
            };
          }
        }
      }}
      columns={columns}
      dataSource={data}
    />
  );
};
```

**Working Sandbox**

[Disabling Rows](https://codesandbox.io/s/selection-ant-design-demo-forked-5bowg?file=/index.js)